# Microsoft Band does not sync Starbucks gift card

Tags: microsoft-band

So in the Tiles view of the Microsoft Health app, I noticed there was integrated functionality for Starbucks cards. I tried adding a Starbucks gift card that I had received to it, and then hit Sync. The tile was added to my Band, but when I enter the tile, it says "Go to Manage Tiles in your app to add a card.", which I had just done.

Is there a step I'm missing, or is this simply an unsolvable glitch?

Comment: Im actually trying to update my starbucks card but my band synced and the starbucks icon is completely gone from my phone and band. Did starbucks remove this service from the band? or is this user (aka me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) error?